# Why do I need to parseInt for number from DynamoDB?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I've been toying around with AWS this last week and started to create a Lambda and play with DynamoDB.

I fought for many hours trying to figure out why I was getting the dreaded `The provided key element does not match the schema` error and I finally broke down and threw in `1` instead of `id`. To my shock, the Lambda finally worked. More toying and I found that I needed to do `parseInt(id)`.

Can someone please explain the reason why? Below is my simple Lambda for updating a column.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB;
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function updateField(id) {
    var params = {
        TableName: 'MyTable',
        Key: {
            'Id': parseInt(id)
        },
        UpdateExpression: `SET #c = :val`,
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#c': 'MyField'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":val": 1
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Updated");
        }
    });
}

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    ddb.scan({
        TableName: 'MyTable',
        Limit: 1
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            var item = data.Items[0];               
            updateField(item.Id.N);
        }
    });
};
```

I am reading the `Id` value right out of DynamoDB and using the `N` property. Why do I need to parse it to an int to reuse it? Is this my failing to understand something so simple in JavaScript or is DynamoDB doing something I am not expecting?

```
//Works
Key: {
   'Id': parseInt(id)
}
//Does not work even though id came right from the database
Key: {
   'Id': id
}
```

Comment: I think there's actually a sensible explanation for this, but would you add the code you're using to fetch the data from DynamoDB so I don't speculate incorrectly, please?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry for the late reply, but the code is there. It's the `export.handler` function at the bottom.

Comment: So it is!  How embarrassing.  I guess I was expecting it to be above, not below, and didn't pay as much attention as I should have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a big difference between responses directly from `AWS.DynamoDB` and `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`. In short, the former will return numbers as strings, while the latter will return numbers as numbers.

You are using both, when you probably should just be using one to avoid issues like this.

```
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB;
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

`DocumentClient` simplifies "pure" DynamoDB calls. From its [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html):

> [DocumentClient] annotates native JavaScript types supplied as input parameters, as well as converts annotated response data to native JavaScript types.

But, while you are using it for your `update`, you are not using `DocumentClient` for your scan. Instead, you are directly using `AWS.DynamoDB` with `ddb.scan()`. This will return differently (and somewhat counter-intuitively) formatted results than DocumentClient. Particularly, from its [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) (look under "Response Syntax"), we see that numbers are returned as strings:

> "N": "string"

So, you can continue casting strings into numbers, or, preferably, swap to doing all common interaction with DynamoDB with `DynamoDB.DocumentClient` as it is designed for better integration with Node/Javascript.

Comment: Ah.. thanks for linking that request documentation and taking your time. Everything makes total sense now. I'll definitely use the `DocumentClient`.